# Save form data to local storage with JavaScript in a Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cordova

I have a simple form that I would like to accept data with and store each input as a local storage variable used as a one time setup.

Here is my current JavaScript and HTML form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function accountSetup(form){
        localStorage.payDayDate = form.setPayDayDate.value;
        localStorage.monthlyTakeHome = form.setMonthlyTakehome.value;
        localStorage.monthlySavingsTarget = form.setSavingsTarget.value;
        console.log("set up complete again");
    }
</script>
```

I have also tried document.getElementById("setPayDayDate").value(); if you think the syntax is incorrect.

```
<form>
        <label>
            Date of pay day:
            <input type="text" id="setPayDayDate" placeholder="23" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Monthly takehome:
            <input type="text" id="setMonthlyTakehome" placeholder="£800" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Savings target:
            <input type="text" id="setSavingsTarget" placeholder="£200" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onClick="accountSetup(this.form)" />
    </form>
```

I also assume that since I haven't set a method or action that the page will just refresh but the localstorage variables will have been set? I do have divs that are meant to display the newly set variables but they still appear empty after the form submission.

Is there some kind of common practice im missing? Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

**Update**

[image: There are no messages/errors in the console log]

There are no messages/errors in the console log

Comment: Is anything being output to your browser's Console window?

Comment: using:

console.log(localStorage.setPayDayDate);
console.log(localStorage.setMonthlyTakehome);
console.log(localStorage.setSavingsTarget);

Literally nothing was output, just empty lines

Comment: No errors or warnings?

Comment: nada! I added an image of my log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so there were quite a few things wrong with this. My first clues came from this very good youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVo3nnloZzw

Using what I learnt there I was able to successfully collect, store and then represent the form data. Here is the updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function accountSetup(){
        var submittedPayDayDate = document.getElementById("setPayDayDate").value;
        var submittedMonthlyTakehome = document.getElementById("setMonthlyTakehome").value;
        var submittedSavingsTarget = document.getElementById("setSavingsTarget").value;
        window.localStorage.setItem("payDayDate", submittedPayDayDate);
        window.localStorage.setItem("monthlyTakehome", submittedMonthlyTakehome);
        window.localStorage.setItem("monthlySavingsTarget", submittedSavingsTarget);
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form method="post" onSubmit="return accountSetup()" data-ajax="false">
        <label>
            Date of pay day:
            <input type="text" id="setPayDayDate" name="setPayDayDate" placeholder="23" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Monthly takehome:
            <input type="text" id="setMonthlyTakehome" name="setMonthlyTakehome" placeholder="£800" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Savings target:
            <input type="text" id="setSavingsTarget" name="setSavingsTarget" placeholder="£200" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate!" />
    </form>
```

To then use the collected data use this line code:

```
window.localStorage.getItem("varName");
```

I hope this turns out to be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use `name="setPayDayDate"` instead-of/in-addition-to the `id=""` on your `form inputs`.